# Spring rest post request with file and other input fields using angular js

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, web-services, rest

I am trying to call a post request by submitting file as an input and other input text fields,my code is below-

Java side-

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "upload",consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, 
 headers={"Content-Type=multipart/form-data"},  produces = {"multipart/form-
 data"},  method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public AjaxResponseData<String> upload(@RequestBody RegisterModel 
 registerModel,@RequestParam(value="file_source", required = false) 
 MultipartFile file) {

 }
```

Angular side -

```
$scope.upload= function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Accept': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        data: {"Name": $scope.name,
            "address": $scope.address,
            "id": $scope.id,
            "phoneNumber": $scope.phone,
            "faxNumber": $scope.fax,
            "email": $scope.email,
            "note": $scope.note,
            "file": $scope.file_source},
            url: '/tps/register/upload'
        }) .then(function(response) { }
    }
```

Whenever i am trying to call its giving Unsupported Media Type with error code 415.

Comment: You are sending JSON not a multipart request...

Comment: "file": $scope.file_source is a file.

Comment: Regardless. You are passing everything as JSON not as a multipart form.

Comment: can you pls let me know how to pass multipart form request with other input fields?

Answer (score 0):

415 error stand for **[Unsupported Media Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors)**:

> The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does
>   not support.

You are sending JSON to your server, but you defined:

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

Change it to

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

---

Same for server side:

```
consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}
```

To:

```
consumes = {"application/json"}
```

Comment: but i am sending file also, can application/json able to handle multipart request?

Comment: @user3864129 In your HTTP POST, I only see JSON. Try what I've suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this code for file upload as i m using it out in my code.
**java code:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public URL uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                 @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

/******* Printing all the possible parameter from @RequestParam *************/

        System.out.println("*****************************");

        System.out.println("file.getOriginalFilename() " + file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("file.getContentType()" + file.getContentType());
        System.out.println("file.getInputStream() " + file.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("file.toString() " + file.toString());
        System.out.println("file.getSize() " + file.getSize());
        System.out.println("name " + name);
        System.out.println("file.getBytes() " + file.getBytes());
        System.out.println("file.hashCode() " + file.hashCode());
        System.out.println("file.getClass() " + file.getClass());
        System.out.println("file.isEmpty() " + file.isEmpty());

        /*************Parameters to b pass to s3 bucket put Object **************/
        InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
        String keyName = file.getOriginalFilename();
}
```

**Angular Code**

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file", "image.jpeg");

var settings = {
 "async": true,
 "crossDomain": true,
 "url": "http://url/",
 "method": "POST",
 "headers": {
   "cache-control": "no-cache"
 },
 "processData": false,
 "contentType": false,
 "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
 "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
});
```